# Conncetivity between two oracle Server

Tags: oracle10g

I have two PC A and B.In both the machine Oracle 10g Express Edition.In this 2 machine both have internet connection with different service provider with different network.Now  i like to connect 2 oracle server by command line sqlplus.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting Remotely with SQL Command Line(Taken from Oracle documentations)

Connecting remotely means running SQL Command Line (SQL*Plus) on one computer (the remote computer), and then initiating a connection to Oracle Database XE on a different computer.

To initiate a remote connection from SQL Command Line using the Oracle Database XE Client:

1. On the remote computer, start a terminal session (Linux) or open a
   command window (Windows.)
   If prompted for host credentials, log in to the remote computer.
2. (Linux only) If the required environment variables are not already set for your session, set them as described in "[Setting Environment Variables on the Linux Platform](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm#CHDJBIAH)".
3. Enter the following command at the operating system prompt:

   `SQLPLUS /NOLOG`
4. Enter a CONNECT command at the SQL Command Line prompt, supplying a
   connect string.
    `CONNECT username/password@[//]host[:port][/service_name]`

   See "[About Remote Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm#CEGIGEIJ)" for a description and examples of
   connect strings.

   See Also:
   ["About Local and Remote Connections"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm#CHDHGDJG)

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for help.It works.

Comment: Accept the answer as solved it will give others chance to see your problem and take help from yours.